# Passing Parameters to Jquery Fadeout Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery fade-out call, and I'm trying to call a function on completion. This  function will call another function inside of it that requires parameters from the object, which this block of code is inside. So first I tried this:

```
MyObject.prototype.myfunction = function myFunction() {
    $(".my-class").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            doSomething(this.one, this.two, this.three, this.four, this.five, this.six, this.seven);
    } );
}
```

But I got an error so now I want to pass the function() after slow some parameters. How would I go about doing that.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Don't use `this` because it refers to the fadeout object, set `var self = this` outside of the fadeout and use `self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` is referring to the wrong object

```
MyObject.prototype.myfunction = function myFunction() {
    var self = this;

    $(".my-class").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            doSomething(self.one, self.two ..);
    } );
}
```

The `this` inside of the fadeout function is referring to the jquery object so setting self to MyObject outside of fadeout and you can use it inside of fadeout. 
Your question dos not explain which object you are trying to pass things from but I assume this is what you want